# Android: Activity with Fragments (Fragments on Top)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on the last days of my Android project but I just have a problem. I have read many tutorials and every solution I read was a fail. 
I would appreciate, if anyone can help me.
Problem: The Fragments are just on the top of the contentHome.xml. But I want, that the layout should chance to the fragment.

**HomeActivity:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) indViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.menu_search) {
        return true;
    }

    return id == R.id.location || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_account) {
        AccountFragment accountFragment = new AccountFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.app_bar,accountFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_favorite) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_inbox) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

**contentHome.xml:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.test.john.test.HomeActivity">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.test.john.test.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/test_logo"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="240dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/testLogo"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@color/iconsText"
        android:text="@string/newMachineText"
        android:id="@+id/btn_NewMachine"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@color/iconsText"
        android:text="@string/accountOverviewText"
        android:id="@+id/btn_AccountOverview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_NewMachine"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@color/iconsText"
        android:text="@string/searchMachineText"
        android:id="@+id/btn_SearchMachine"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn_AccountOverview"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**AccountFragment:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.test.john.test.AccountFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


<CalendarView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/calendarView" />
```

Comment: I've read a lot of stackoverflow question like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309815/fragments-displayed-over-each-other

But the solution doesnt worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a layout as a container inside contentHome will do the trick. Try reading this, maybe it will help you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html