# Fragments are stacking on top of each other

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

In Android Studio, I started a new project with "BottomNavigationView" and now when I run the application in the emulator, the Home Fragment is there by default but then is never replaced when I switch to another fragment. Instead, the new fragments replace each other while still being on top of the first fragment. So if I had 3 fragments, fragment 1 stays stuck in the activity while fragment 1 (duplicate), fragment 2, and fragment 3 all replace each other on top of fragment 1 (original). I don't know how to get rid of the original fragment, or where it is even coming from. I'm new to Android development and learning Kotlin so I am struggling to find suggestions in Kotlin. Here is the code in my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.android.pointmax


import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.android.pointmax.ui.home.HomeFragment
import com.example.android.pointmax.ui.recommended.RecommendedFragment
import com.example.android.pointmax.ui.wallet.WalletFragment
import timber.log.Timber


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_home-> {
                val fragment = HomeFragment.newInstance()
                replaceFragment(fragment)
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_wallet -> {
                replaceFragment(WalletFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_recommended -> {
                replaceFragment(RecommendedFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Plant tree to enable Debugging with Timber
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())

        // Find the bottomNavigation bar
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        // Find the fragment that will host the different fragments
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_wallet, R.id.navigation_recommended))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        // Set click listeners to respond to bottom navigation selections
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment,fragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

The MainActivity.xml is how it is created by default, with a constraintLayout, with a bottomNavigationView and nav_host_fragment nested underneath. I greatly appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try looking at this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309815/fragments-displayed-over-each-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this weird navigation behavior is because you are trying two methods of navigation at the same time

**1. Navigation component**

**2. Fragment Manager**

While using Android **Jetpack's Navigation component**, you should create Navigation graphs and use them for navigating between fragments.

This link should help you learn more about the the Navigation graphs.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph

Comment: I see my problem was that I never checked to see the menu items were pointing to the correct locations as they kept the default ID names, and so I developed an elaborate way of stacking two systems on top of each other, rather than fixing that main issue. I removed all of the extra code on having clickListeners and just followed your link.Thank you for your help!