# How to Fix Fragment Overwriting on Top of each other?

Tags: android

> This is the Issue :

[image]

> For some reason, everytime, a new Instance of the Fragment is created on top of the existing one, which gives this weird type of UI.

> This is my code :

```
final Fragment fragment1 = new HomeFragment();
final Fragment fragment2 = new ProfileFragment();
final Fragment fragment3 = new MapsFragment();
Fragment active = fragment1; //make the first screen as your active fragment.
final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment1, "1").commit();

    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("loginToken", MODE_PRIVATE);
    getToken = myPrefs.getString("token", null);

}
```

> How to fix this Issue ? Please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: for example you can try no to add unused fragments, and show them only when you will need it. you have three fragments transactions in one time, what is not good I think.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use ViewPager 2 (or 3) and androidx.navigation libraries in order to avoid such issues. You'll get multiple benefits and a stable app. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view-2
If you have to do it with fragment manager, similar questions have been answered multiple times here on Stackoverflow. For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309815/fragments-displayed-over-each-other

Also refer to fm documentation (use replace(), not hide()): 
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#add-remove

Answer (score 0):

Add in every layout on the parent of the view in XML.

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="#fff"

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#fff">

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layouts background in default are transparen, so just put a background color and the new elements fragment, not display over old fragment